# Transform from relative to world space in Processing

Tags: java, transformation, processing, coordinate-transformation

What is a good way of transforming a local relative point, into the world (screen) space in Processing?

For example, take the [Flocking example](http://processing.org/learning/topics/flocking.html) that comes with the Processing PDE. How would I implement a `relativeToWorld` method and a `worldToRelative` method in the `Boid` class. These methods would take into consideration, all the transforms done in the `render` method.

I was thinking I would want to transform PVector objects, so the method signatures might look something like:

```
PVector relativeToWorld(PVector relative) {
    // Take a relative PVector and return a world PVector.
}

PVector worldToRelative(PVector world) {
    // Take a world PVector and return a relative PVector.
}
```

Comment: This post may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339533/transform-screen-coordinates-to-model-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Processing doesn't make life easy with such things. It doesn't provide us access to transformation matrices, so I believe we have to use a manual transformation matrix/vector multiplication. (If you're curious, I used frame-to-canonical transformation matrices in homogeneous representation).

**WARNING**:
This is a Mathematica result quickly interpreted in java which is assuming you only have **one rotation** and **one translation** (as in the render method). The translation is only given by the loc PVector.

```
PVector relativeToWorld(PVector relative) {
  float theta = vel.heading2D() + PI/2;
  float r00 = cos(theta);
  float r01 = -sin(theta);
  float r10 = -r01;
  float r11 = r00;
  PVector world = new PVector();
  world.x = relative.x * r00 + relative.y*r01 + loc.x;
  world.y = relative.x * r10 + relative.y*r11 + loc.y;
  return world;
}

PVector worldToRelative(PVector world) {
  float theta = vel.heading2D() + PI/2;
  float r00 = cos(theta);
  float r01 = sin(theta);
  float r10 = -r01;
  float r11 = r00;
  PVector relative = new PVector();
  relative.x = world.x*r00 + world.y*r10 - loc.x*r00 - loc.y*r10;
  relative.y = world.x*r01 + world.y*r11 - loc.x*r01 - loc.y*r11;
  return relative;
}
```

Comment: Are all the x's and y's correct in your code? And I think where you are setting relative in the last few lines, it should be setting the x and y properties?

Comment: Corrected the relative.x/y. Does it work for you? I tested it now and it seems to do fine, no? Again, not the best solution because it's limited to only one translation and rotation.

Comment: Works perfectly. I just had to have time to test it :) Thanks for testing and for the edit.

Comment: I believe you left out a minus sign in the worldToRelative function.  Should be float r01 = -sin(theta);  Spent a while trying to figure that out.